# Are the commands search, try and tryall commands available in OPL?

Tags: cplex, opl

Reading the book ["The OPL Optimization Programming Language"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262720302) written by Pascal Van Hentenryck I saw some examples of use commands **search**, **try**, **tryall**, etc.

Please see below an example from the book :

```
search {
   forall(w in Warehouses)
      when open[w] = 0 do
          forall(c in Customers)
             supply[c] <> w;
   forall(w in Warehouses)
      try open[w] = 0 | open[w] = 1 endtry;

};
```

This kind of instruction will work in recent versions of OPL?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This was working in very old versions opl 3.7 but you do not need to do that for 13 years.

You simply model and run.